# C# Telegram Bot публикация Deploy-F или Asp.NetCore

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, asp.net-core, deploy, deploy-f

вопрос таков. Написать самого бота не проблема. Возникает вопрос о публикации бота на хостинг\сервер чтобы многие пользователи могли обращаться к командам бота одновременно.

Видел что можно написать бота как консольное приложение Net.Core и загрузить на Deploy-F или аналогичный хостинг.

Так же кто то пишет ботов как Asp.NetCore WebAplication и затем публикует на vds
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: ну, консольное приложение будет проблематично захостить, оно для того не предназначено, а вот asp.net для того и сделан. Найдите хостинг под asp.net и почитайте в документации хостинга, как правильно на него опубликовать сайт с помощью студии

Comment: Хорошо тогда лучше так сделать, до этого как раз и задавался этим вопросом, очень много примеров консольного приложения и затем его публикации на хостинг или Deployt, но с точки зрения консольное приложение это не обертка сайта над ботом. а простое приложение. Если использовать консольное, то скорее всего нужна vds с подходящими настройками для распаралеливания приложения? Кто то писал про  это, но звучит  странно.